# Why Et(X) is not small?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, according to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_cohomology the category of étale $X$-morphisms is not small, how to see this?

Comment: Well, the canonical map from a disjoint union of copies of $X$ to $X$ is étale, and there are a proper class of isomorphism classes of these things.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If $I$ is any set, then the canonical morphism $\coprod_{i \in I} X \to X$ is étale (indeed, a local isomorphism in the Zariski topology). There is obviously a proper class of isomorphism classes of these étale $X$-schemes.
2. Despite what Wikipedia says, that means the category of étale $X$-schemes is not even essentially small.
3. Under good situations, one can obtain a petit étale site that is essentially small; for instance, when $X$ is locally noetherian. This is done by restricting to the full subcategory of étale $X$-schemes that are of finite presentation over $X$ (and not merely *locally* of finite presentation over $X$).

Comment: Why do you assume X noetherian in 3.? I've seen this restriction for general X.

Comment: I find it convenient to have all affine open subschemes of $X$ to be in the site – locally noetherian ensures this happens. I suppose it's unnecessary because the basic affine open subschemes are always of finite presentation.