# Importance of Et(X) not being small?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

It was asked earlier ([Why Et(X) is not small?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431609/why-etx-is-not-small/431700#431700))  why $Et(X)$, the category of schemes etale over a fixed scheme $X$ is not small. I was wondering how does this issue come up in practice? I'm guessing somewhere in the development of say etale cohomology (which I don't know much about), one needs to work with a category that is small. What is an example of such an instance?

The following similar question had useful answers
[Importance of 'smallness' in a category, and functor categories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105737/importance-of-smallness-in-a-category-and-functor-categories)

and one of the answers said that to form the category of presheaves on a category $C$ (such as $C=Et(X)$) you need $C$ to be small, since if $C$ is a proper class, then the presheaf category $[C^{op}, Sets]$ is certainly not small and someone suspected it might not even be a class. 
But in the development of etale cohomology, are there results where we really need to consider all presheaves on $Et(X)$ at once, and not just some (say a class or set) of presheaves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sheaves associated to presheaves usually only exist on small sites.